# Upload data to the TelosB in Contiki

Tags: upload, contiki

I am a newbie of the Contiki System. I am trying to upload binary data (in
txt. format, it is some recorded interference) to the TelosB node to regenerate
interference (the data file is in large size, 5M for example), in other words, I am trying to use Contiki to read binary files and send to the node. I googled
this problem, but did not found much useful information.

Could anyone give me some idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to send data from/to your TelosB is to just send it to the tty associated with the USB port it's connected to (e.g., /dev/ttyUSB0). Your TelosB will be able to simply read the data from stdin (and vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as there is a lot of data in the txt file (>5M), I cannot input them all by myself. Actually I am looking for a way to  make the node automatically read data from the txt file and send them (to another node). Do you have any ideas? (I also modified my question to make it clearer.)

Comment: You do not have to manually type data to send it to a tty. Linux offers tools to do that.